# Can't stop javafx tables from ignoring my the setter function validation

Tags: validation, javafx, textfield

I'm using javafx to do some table stuff. I want to validate my textfields in the myTextRow Class. In the "setText2" method I check the input if it is not bigger than 6 symbols, but it has no effects at all.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Supermain extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        ArrayList myindizes=new ArrayList();



        final TableView<myTextRow> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);
        table.setStyle("-fx-text-wrap: true;");

        //Table columns
        TableColumn<myTextRow, String> clmID = new TableColumn<>("ID");
        clmID.setMinWidth(160);
        clmID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ID"));

        TableColumn<myTextRow, String> clmtext = new TableColumn<>("Text");
        clmtext.setMinWidth(160);
        clmtext.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("text"));
        clmtext.setCellFactory(new TextFieldCellFactory());

        TableColumn<myTextRow, String> clmtext2 = new TableColumn<>("Text2");
        clmtext2.setMinWidth(160);
        clmtext2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("text2"));
        clmtext2.setCellFactory(new TextFieldCellFactory());

        //Add data
        final ObservableList<myTextRow> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new myTextRow(5, "Lorem","bla"),
                new myTextRow(2, "Ipsum","bla")
        );

        table.getColumns().addAll(clmID, clmtext,clmtext2);
        table.setItems(data);

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setSpacing(5.0);
        hBox.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Get Data");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                for (myTextRow data1 : data) {
                    System.out.println("data:" + data1.getText2());
                }
            }
        });

        hBox.getChildren().add(btn);

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setTop(hBox);
        pane.setCenter(table);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 640, 480));
        primaryStage.show();


    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    public static class TextFieldCellFactory
            implements Callback<TableColumn<myTextRow, String>, TableCell<myTextRow, String>> {

        @Override
        public TableCell<myTextRow, String> call(TableColumn<myTextRow, String> param) {
            TextFieldCell textFieldCell = new TextFieldCell();
            return textFieldCell;
        }

        public static class TextFieldCell extends TableCell<myTextRow, String> {

            private TextArea textField;
            private StringProperty boundToCurrently = null;

            public TextFieldCell() {

                textField = new TextArea();
                textField.setWrapText(true);
                textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);

                this.setGraphic(textField);
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (!empty) {
                    // Show the Text Field
                    this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);


                   // myindizes.add(getIndex());

                    // Retrieve the actual String Property that should be bound to the TextField
                    // If the TextField is currently bound to a different StringProperty
                    // Unbind the old property and rebind to the new one
                    ObservableValue<String> ov = getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(getIndex());
                    SimpleStringProperty sp = (SimpleStringProperty) ov;

                    if (this.boundToCurrently == null) {
                        this.boundToCurrently = sp;
                        this.textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(sp);
                    } else if (this.boundToCurrently != sp) {
                        this.textField.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(this.boundToCurrently);
                        this.boundToCurrently = sp;
                        this.textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(this.boundToCurrently);
                    }

                    double height = real_lines_height(textField.getText(), this.getWidth(), 30, 22);
                    textField.setPrefHeight(height);
                    textField.setMaxHeight(height);

                    textField.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                    // if height bigger than the biggest height in the row
                    //-> change all heights of the row(textfields ()typeof textarea) to this height
                    // else leave the height as it is


                    //System.out.println("item=" + item + " ObservableValue<String>=" + ov.getValue());
                    //this.textField.setText(item);  // No longer need this!!!
                } else {
                    this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
                }
            }

        }

    }

    public class myTextRow {

        private final SimpleIntegerProperty ID;

        private final SimpleStringProperty text;
        private final SimpleStringProperty text2;

        public myTextRow(int ID, String text,String text2) {

            this.ID = new SimpleIntegerProperty(ID);
            this.text = new SimpleStringProperty(text);
            this.text2 = new SimpleStringProperty(text2);


        }

        public void setID(int id) {
            this.ID.set(id);
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text.set(text);
        }

        public void setText2(String text) {
            if(text2check(text)){
            this.text2.set(text);}
            else
            {System.out.println("wrong value!!!");}
        }

        public int getID() {
            return ID.get();
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text.get();
        }

        public StringProperty textProperty() {
        return text;

        }

        public String getText2() {
            return text2.get();
        }

        public StringProperty text2Property() {
        return text2;

        }

    public IntegerProperty IDProperty() {
        return ID;
    }

    public boolean text2check(String t)
    {
       if(t.length()>6)return false;
       return true;
    }
    }

    private static double real_lines_height(String s, double width, double heightCorrector, double widthCorrector) {
        HBox h = new HBox();
        Label l = new Label("Text");
        h.getChildren().add(l);
        Scene sc = new Scene(h);
        l.applyCss();
        double line_height = l.prefHeight(-1);

        int new_lines = s.replaceAll("[^\r\n|\r|\n]", "").length();
        //  System.out.println("new lines= "+new_lines);
        String[] lines = s.split("\r\n|\r|\n");
        //  System.out.println("line count func= "+ lines.length);
        int count = 0;
        //double rest=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            double text_width = get_text_width(lines[i]);
            double plus_lines = Math.ceil(text_width / (width - widthCorrector));
            if (plus_lines > 1) {
                count += plus_lines;
                //rest+= (text_width / (width-widthCorrector)) - plus_lines;
            } else {
                count += 1;
            }

        }
        //count+=(int) Math.ceil(rest);
        count += new_lines - lines.length;

        return count * line_height + heightCorrector;
    }

    private static double get_text_width(String s) {
        HBox h = new HBox();
        Label l = new Label(s);
        l.setWrapText(false);
        h.getChildren().add(l);
        Scene sc = new Scene(h);
        l.applyCss();
        // System.out.println("dubbyloop.FXMLDocumentController.get_text_width(): "+l.prefWidth(-1));
        return l.prefWidth(-1);

    }

}
```

Comment: i thought it was called automatically by the ObservableList "data" via the TextFieldCellFactory..

Comment: Where do you call `setText()` ?

Comment: No: it calls the setter directly on the property (i.e. `text2Property().setValue()`), not via the set method you define in the model class. The problem with your code is that you're violating a rule of the JavaFX properties pattern: `xProperty().setValue(value)` should always be identical to `setX(value)`.

Comment: how can i make it identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rule of the JavaFX Properties pattern is that for a property `x`, invoking  `xProperty().setValue(value)` should always be identical to invoking `setX(value)`. Your validation makes this not true. The binding your cell implementation uses invokes the `setValue` method on the property, which is why it bypasses your validation check.

(Side note: in all the code I am going to change the names so that they adhere to proper [naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java).)

The default way to implement a property in this pattern is:

```
public class MyTextRow {

    private final StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public StringProperty textProperty() {
        return text ;
    }

    public final void setText(String text) {
        textProperty().set(text);
    }

    public final String getText() {
        return textProperty().get();
    }
}
```

By having the set/get methods delegate to the appropriate property methods, you are guaranteed these rules are enforced, even if the `textProperty()` methods is overridden in a subclass. Making the set and get methods final ensures that the rule is not broken by a subclass overriding those methods.

One approach might be to override the `set` and `setValue` methods in the property, as follows:

```
public class MyTextRow {

    private final StringProperty text2 = new StringPropertyBase() {
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "text2";
        }
        @Override
        public Object getBean() {
            return MyTextRow.this ;
        }
        @Override
        public void setValue(String value) {
            if (text2Check(value)) {
                super.setValue(value);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void set(String value) {
            if (text2Check(value)) {
                super.set(value);
            }
        }
    }

    public StringProperty text2Property() {
        return text2 ;
    }

    public final void setText2(String text2) {
        text2Property().set(text2);
    }

    public final String getText2() {
        return text2Property().get();
    }

    // ...
}
```

however, I think this will break the bidirectional binding that you have with the `text` property in the `TextArea` (basically, there is no way to communicate back to the text area when a change is vetoed, so the text area will not know to revert to the previous value). One fix would be to implement your cell using listeners on the properties instead of bindings. You could use a `TextFormatter` on the text area that simply updates the property and vetoes the text change if the change doesn't occur.

Here is a complete SSCCE using this approach:

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter.Change;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class VetoStringChange extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);
        table.getColumns().add(column("Item", Item::nameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Description", Item::descriptionProperty));

        for (int i = 1; i <= 20 ; i++) {
            table.getItems().add(new Item("Item "+i, ""));
        }

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(table, 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static <S> TableColumn<S,String> column(String title, Function<S,Property<String>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,String> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));

        col.setCellFactory(tc -> new TextAreaCell<S>(property));
        col.setPrefWidth(200);

        return col ;
    }

    public static class TextAreaCell<S> extends TableCell<S, String> {

        private TextArea textArea ;

        public TextAreaCell(Function<S, Property<String>> propertyAccessor) {

            textArea = new TextArea();
            textArea.setWrapText(true);
            textArea.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
            textArea.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);

            UnaryOperator<Change> filter = c -> {
                String proposedText = c.getControlNewText() ;
                Property<String> prop = propertyAccessor.apply(getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()));
                prop.setValue(proposedText);
                if (prop.getValue().equals(proposedText)) {
                    return c ;
                } else {
                    return null ;
                }
            };
            textArea.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>(filter));
            this.setGraphic(textArea);
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (!empty) {

                if (! textArea.getText().equals(item)) {
                    textArea.setText(item);
                }

                // Show the Text Field
                this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            } else {
                this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
            }
        }

    }



    public static class Item {
        private final StringProperty name = new StringPropertyBase() {

            @Override
            public Object getBean() {
                return Item.this;
            }

            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return "name" ;
            }

            @Override
            public void set(String value) {
                if (checkValue(value)) {
                    super.set(value);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void setValue(String value) {
                if (checkValue(value)) {
                    super.setValue(value);
                }
            }

        };
        private final StringProperty description = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Item(String name, String description) {
            setName(name);
            setDescription(description);
        }

        private boolean checkValue(String value) {
            return value.length() <= 6 ;
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public final String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setName(final String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }

        public final StringProperty descriptionProperty() {
            return this.description;
        }

        public final String getDescription() {
            return this.descriptionProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setDescription(final String description) {
            this.descriptionProperty().set(description);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Another approach is to allow a "commit and revert" type strategy on your property:

```
public class MyTextRow {

    private final StringProperty text2 = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public MyTextRow() {
        text2.addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> {
            if (! checkText2(newText)) {
                // sanity check:
                if (checkText2(oldText)) {
                    text2.set(oldText);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public StringProperty text2Property() {
        return text ;
    }

    public final void setText2(String text2) {
        text2Property().set(text2);
    }

    public final String getText2() {
        return text2Property().get();
    }
}
```

In general I dislike validation by listening for an invalid value and reverting like this, because other listeners to the property will see all the changes, including changes to and from invalid values. However, this might be the best option in this case.

Finally, you could consider vetoing invalid changes as in the first option, and also setting a `TextFormatter` on the control in the cell that simply doesn't allow text entry that results in an invalid string. This isn't always possible from a usability perspective (e.g. if empty strings are invalid, you almost always want to allow the user to temporarily delete all the text), and it means keeping two validation checks in sync in your code, which is a pain.

Comment: puuh..thanks for your answer.. i will never do a new project in java again because in compare to html/js with jquery this is absolutely not handleable. you have no easy access to your elements.maybe it is even easier to embed a html file and do ajax requests to the java application to communicate between each other.

Comment: Well, you're not comparing like to like. JavaFX is a desktop UI toolkit, not a web application toolkit. It's designed to hook into highly robust business logic. JavaFX is not perfect by any means, but you can't compare it to a web page technology where the backend tiers are implemented server-side (more often than not in Java...). If you are only interested in developing front-end, why don't you just validate in the cell with a `TextFormatter`? Or, just do the equivalent of what you describe using web technologies and delegate the business to a server with web service requests.

Comment: I actually don't think this is nearly as hard as you seem to think it is. I updated with an example of a cell implementation of the kind I was intending. It would actually be fairly easy to factor out the `StringProperty` implementation (`VetoableStringProperty`) and make it even cleaner. Is this really worth having such a fit about?

Comment: jokely,yes it is ^^ and sure i can compare javaFx with html/js, why not? javafx is is doing UI and html/js is also doing just the UI. In Jquery(JS) i would just do inside the cell $.parent('tr').find('textarea').each(function(calcHeight){this.css({'height':calcHeight}); )}; -> and the TASK IS DONE

Comment: I'm not a big time JS user but I cannot see any way that would implement vetoing a change to a string value in a domain object. It looks like that is calculating the height of all text areas in a table: I don't understand what that has to do with your question. Desktop UI is not the same as web UI, period.

Comment: sorry this example was out of the context.to point out for this example it would be $(document).on('blur','textarea',function(){ if(!checkSyntaxOfTextarea($(this).val()) {$(this).val('last value of textarea')} } )};

Comment: so how can you check the value of the arraylist when you lost the focus? and just change your data arraylist when you lost the focus? (in an easy way like in jquery? ;))

Comment: `textArea.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> { if (! isNowFocused && ! isValid(textArea.getText())) { // revert data }});`. But obviously in this environment (again, different to web programming) you want to do your validation in the model, not the view.

Comment: The discussion is getting quite boring now: in general whining about a technology is not interesting. All these different technologies were designed by people with far more talent than either you or me, and the design decisions made were made for very carefully considered reasons with specific classes of use case in mind. Either you like it or you don't: but I have answered your question about how to use it.